# Задание по Python - с конфетами

Tags: python

Задание: Дано вещественное число – цена 1 кг конфет. Вывести стоимость 1, 2, … 10 кг конфет. Решить задачу используя циклическую конструкцию for.

Нужна помощь, в чем проблема, я сделал, только совсем не тот ответ (и то с ошибками). Заранее благодарю.

```
un = float(input('КГ = '))
for i in range(1, 1.1 // 10):
    landungalia = i*un
print('{} кг стоит {}'.format(i, landungalia))
```

Comment: Нужно читать текст ошибок. Заодно рекомендую перечитать главу про for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = float(input())

for x in range(1, 11):
  print(x*p)
```

Comment: Код будет работать корректно без float? Если число будет с плавающей точкой?

Comment: Python - язык с динамической типизацией, он сам поймет что имеет дело с float, важно чтобы для Вас это не стало сюрпризом в неожиданный момент. Хочу отметить что в данном примере цена будет чрезмерно точной, т.е. чисел после запятой будет больше чем два. Чтобы привести результат к денежному формату используйте библиотеку numbers

Comment: Замечание для пользователя @C1oud: В сообществе SOF принято не редактировать чужой код напрямую, если это касается принципов работы кода. Если в коде есть неточность (не опечатка, а именно неточность) - лучше поправить автора ответа в комментариях

Comment: @Евгений, если перед именем не ставить `@`, то уведомление ему не придёт. Ну и в принципе вроде он нормально поправил. К тому же, на правку приходит уведомление.

Comment: @Qwertiy странно, у меня не работало упоминание через `@`, если упоминаемый пользователь ничего не писал в комментариях. Оно просто убиралось из текста комментария

Comment: @Евгений, если он правил сообщение, либо был последним, кто закрыл/открыл вопрос, должно работать. Ну и я же в твоём комменте поменял на `@` - ничего не удалилось. Вроде убирается только имя единственного комментатора, а всякие левые имена просто не работают, но и не убираются.